# How do I finish this program for a Caeser cipher?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I'm working on a program that will decipher a Caesar cipher. When I run the program there is no output. Thank you in advance!

Here is my code

```
def test():
    value = input("Value here!") 
    with open ("cipher.*txt") as f:

        nice_strings = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip() 
            nice_str_chars = []

            for char in line:

                int_of_char = ord(char)

                int_of_char += value 
                nice_char = chr(int_of_char)

                nice_str_chars.append(nice_char)

            nice_str = ''.join(nice_str_chars)

            nice_strings.append(nice_str)

            print (line, '=>', nice_str, '\n')

        return nice_strings
```

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service.  Please read the [help] before posting again.

Comment: You almost certainly don't have a file called `cipher.*txt`.

Comment: A hint: that addition needs more work. But it seems you are on the right trace.

Comment: @zyflair here is a random thought: on stackoverflow, starting questions with 'help me with my homework' is generally considered bad form. The community has generally been more accepting of: keep it simple: `here is my code, here is my input, here is my output, here is my expected output, can you help me understand why I don't get the expected output` 
This approach seems to get more positive attention and result in fewer downvotes. Even if the code you are writing is for homework. = )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems jump out at me:

This function is never called, in the code you have presented.

There appears to be a problem with the filename

There is a need to convert the input value to an integer so that the math will work...

```
def test():
    ### convert the input to an integer
    value = int(input("Value here!"))

    ### presuming you want 'cipher.txt' versus 'cipher.*txt'
    with open ("cipher.txt") as f:      

        nice_strings = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip() 
            nice_str_chars = []

            for char in line:
                int_of_char = ord(char)
                int_of_char += value 
                nice_char = chr(int_of_char)
                nice_str_chars.append(nice_char)

            nice_str = ''.join(nice_str_chars)
            nice_strings.append(nice_str)
            print (line, '=>', nice_str, '\n')

        return nice_strings

### don't forget to call your function:

test()
```